# Why is my SpotLight casting a perfect circle?

Tags: three.js

I am having a hard time figuring out why my three.js SpotLight is behaving the way it is. I am trying to make a flashlight for a game. I am adding the SpotLight to the scene like this:

```
flashLight = new THREE.SpotLight( 0xffffff, 1 );
scene.add( flashLight );
```

And then updating the flashlight to move in sync with the player like this:

```
flashLight.position.copy(player.body.position);

flashLight.target.position.set(flashLight.position.x + player.lookDirection.x,
                             flashLight.position.y + player.lookDirection.y,
                             flashLight.position.z + player.lookDirection.z);

flashLight.target.updateMatrixWorld();
```

For some reason, the flashlight casts a perfect circle on the surfaces that it shines on: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ll76M.png)

The expected behaviour is demonstrated [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ALXNYQ)

Thanks!

Comment: Are you viewing it from the same perspective of the flash light? Perhaps offset your flash light as if it were off center of the player. I think your problem is `flashLight.position.copy(player.body.position);` You're 1:1'ing the position

Comment: You're exactly right. Slightly embarassed. Thank you!

Comment: What you could try is having a trigger that when it creates your flashlight, fix it at those co-ordinates then allow your player to move around it, looking at it from different angles. every time you turn it off/on, set the orientation so you can try viewing its beam from different view points.

_Note: that I have never used three.js, I really liked your question, it was fun!_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the demo, you can see it takes the camera position but offsets it a little

```
        flashLight.position.copy(camera.position);
        flashLight.position.x += 2;
        flashLight.position.y -= 3;
        flashLight.position.z -= 1;
```

I feel you are seeing a perfect circle, because you're viewing the beam from the same angle as its source.